# Counting number of relationships for a specific node in neo4j graph database

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

My data model is `(:User)-[:LIKE]->(:Pull)`.
I'm trying to count the number of likes relationship for a specific `Pull` using this query:

```
PROFILE
MATCH res=(:Pull {id:"pull4"})<-[:LIKE]-()
return  size(collect(relationships((res)))) as res
```

The problem is I'm expanding all the relationships and then counting them, which is very expensive if a `Pull` has millions of likes.

Is there a better query with count stores in neo4j?

Sample of  old solutions that fails now with latest version of NEO4J DBMS:

```
MATCH (p:Pull {id:"pull4"})
RETURN size(  (p)<-[:LIKE]-() )
```

```
MATCH (p:Pull {id:"pull4"})
RETURN length(  (p)<-[:LIKE]-() )
```

Comment: what is your neo4j version? Thanks

Comment: @jose_bacoy latest version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

```
MATCH (p:Pull {id:"pull4"}) RETURN size( [ (p)-[:LIKE]-() | p]  )
```